# Problem running basic Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, curl

I have been working through an introductory [Spring Boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch).

I have gotten as far as running

`./mvnw spring-boot:run`

From the project directory.

Which generates the output:

```
Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:
application
beanNameHandlerMapping
defaultServletHandlerMapping
dispatcherServlet
embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor
handlerExceptionResolver
helloController
httpRequestHandlerAdapter
messageSource
mvcContentNegotiationManager
mvcConversionService
mvcValidator
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration
propertySourcesBinder
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
requestMappingHandlerAdapter
requestMappingHandlerMapping
resourceHandlerMapping
simpleControllerHandlerAdapter
tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
viewControllerHandlerMapping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.530 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-18T14:29:53-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run `$ curl localhost:8080`
from a seperate terminal window
instead of the expected:

`Greetings from Spring Boot!`

I get:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreacted.

Thank you

Comment: Did you hit Ctrl-C to stop the ./mvnw spring-boot:run command? Because if you did, you stopped the server.

Comment: @JBNizet I did not hit Ctrl-C, however, the command completes on its own and returns to the input line. I now realize that this indicates the server is not running. I will have to find out why that is.
Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: You should have more output than that in the console. Probably containing an error message explaining what the problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet there seems to have been a problem in my pom.xml file... I copied the one directly from the tutorial rather than using the one from Spring initializer, which I admittedly tinkered with... and it now works.

Comment: You have to start your app . run ./mvnw spring-boot:run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow below steps in command line and worked successfully:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git
```

after cloning completed a new directory gs-spring-boot will be created then change directory to gs-spring-boot/initial

```
cd gs-spring-boot/initial
```

then run following command

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

if you already have installed maven and available in your path instead you can use following command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

then spring application start to run after spring boot application start up finished without pressing Ctrl+c and terminating application switch to postman and point to address:

```
localhost:8080
```

then you will see expected result as below

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the pom.xml from Spring initializer has a wrong dependency.

When you use Spring initializer here https://start.spring.io/, one of the dependencies in pom.xml looks like this

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

However on https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/blob/master/complete, https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/tree/master/initial and the tutorial page https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/, that dependency in pom.xml should be this

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

adding -web to that dependency would fix this.

Answer (score 1):

After copying the pom.xml file directly from the tutorial I have noticed what is probably an important difference:

new(working):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

old:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Notice spring-boot-start-*web* vs spring-boot-starter

Based on info from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453745/spring-initializr-spring-boot-starter-vs-spring-boot-starter-web)
spring-boot-starter-web includes:

- spring-boot-starter
- jackson
- spring-core
- spring-mvc
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Originally I had used spring-boot-starter rather than spring-boot-starter-web and added spring-mvc manually. Most likely some of those other dependencies are required as well.